# Button keeps opening lots of links

Tags: c#

I have made a button redirect you to a link but it keeps constantly opening it and messing up. I have made it so when you press it it start timer 1 then it redirects you, starts timer 2 and stops timer 1. But it doesn't stop it it just keeps opening loads of tabs.

The code I am using is this

```
Process.Start("https://mobile.twitter.com/logout");
```

And I am also using threading so I can pause the thread for a bit of time

Comment: You are new here, so please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please post the relevant code, the issue is to do with the action looping, not the action itself - what are the timers doing, does your threading break it etc.